# Making a Calculator using multiple classes

Tags: java, math, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to make a calculator with multiple classes, however I am not that experienced with classes. I've been having a few problems with it.

This is the user input section, doesn't seem to have any problems

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GetData 
    {    
    Scanner getdata = new Scanner(System.in);
    public double intx;
    public double inty;
                
    public void getInt() {
       System.out.print("Enter a number");
       double intx = getdata.nextDouble(); 
    }
           
   public void getDouble() {
      System.out.print("Enter a double");
      double inty = getdata.nextDouble(); 
   }
}
```

This is the operation section, the most problems are happening here, as said in the error there are missing error statements,

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;

  public class MathOps {
     
         Scanner mathops = new Scanner(System.in);
         public double x; 
         public double y;
         public double answer;
     
        public double add(int x, int y) {
           System.out.println("Adding " + x + "and " + y);
           return x + y;
        }
    
        public double multiply(int x, int y) {
           System.out.println("Multiplying " + x + "and " + y);
           return x * y;
        }
    
        public double sub(int x, int y) {
           System.out.println("Subtracting " + x + "and " + y);
           if(x >= y) {
              return x - y; }
           if(y >= x) {
              return y - x; }
        } 
    
        public double divide() {
           System.out.println("Dividing " + x + "and " + y);
           if(x >= y) {
              return x / y; }
           if(y >= x) {
              return y / x; }
        }
      }
```

> ```
> ----jGRASP exec: javac -g MathOps.java
>     MathOps.java:27: error: missing return statement
>                 }
>                 ^
>     MathOps.java:35: error: missing return statement
>                 }
>                 ^
>     2 errors
>
>  ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.  ----jGRASP: operation
> complete.
> ```

This is were I'm putting it all together, also has problems

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class L3Operations
{
   int geti;
   int getd;
   
    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          //instatnate
         Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
     
         int x1 = a.getInt();
       }
}
```

Comment: From the compiler's point of view you don't return a value in all possible paths in `sub()` and `divide()` methods. Use `else` instead of the second `if`.

Comment: `Scanner` does not have method `getInt()`. Did you perhaps meant `Scanner.nextInt()`, or maybe `GetData.getInt()`?

Comment: Don't correct the expression based on comparisons.  A negative number  for subtraction is a valid answer and so is a reciprocal (e.g. a/b vs b/a).  Most folks understand that it is `a op b` and they need to deal with it.  But you can check for bad things like division by zero and provide a message or let the calculator display the exception.  Also, you divide method is missing parameters.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, correcting the expressions will also make your calculator pretty useless.

Comment: Can you provide a sample user interaction?  How does the user interact with your program?  Do they enter input like  5 + 2?  Does your app display a menu for user to pick what operations to perform?  Without this knowledge, you can't write your program (main class).

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, note that x >= y and y >= x will both be false if either x or y is Double.NaN, and you can enter NaN as a double value with the Scanner class (and also Infinity and -Infinity). So unless you check the values ahead of time to rule out NaN, you can't assume that at least one of those two conditions will be true.

You also can't assume that if x > y and y > x are false, then x == y, because for NaN all of those are false. And, if you have just assigned x = y, you can't assume that x == y, since if y was NaN that will be false.